# How can I start a GUI application on the Raspberry PI before logging in?

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, autostart, on-screen-keyboard

I have the Raspberry Pi 4. Basically, I get along well and I have a lot of Linux know-how. I know all (startup) concepts like systemd, init.d, autostart and cronjobs. However, I can't manage to start an application (on-screen keyboard) automatically **before** logging in.

It doesn't work with crontab and autostart, because the application is only started after login. I have therefore set auto-login. This is only a temporary solution for me. I would really like to have the application start automatically **before** login. What kind of hints/ideas do you have for this?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: How about a `systemd` service requiring multiuser?